# GERAR RELATORIO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mpdf, dompdf, codeigniter-3

Tenho um banco de dados no qual possui duas tabelas:

**CLIENTES**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**BOLETOS**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No minha VIEW (Codeigniter), o usuário irá selecionar um período (Ex. 01/03/2018 a 31/03/2018) para gerar um relatório de todos os boletos que foram pagos dentro deste periodo.

Neste relatorio, preciso que todas as informaçãos daquele periodo saia no relatorio mas ordenando por grupo, exmplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou utilizando o Codeigniter3 e pensando em utilizar mPDF para os relatorios.
Alguem poderia me ajudar com essa logica?

Comment: O mPDF é bom, mas por segurança pense em gerar em formato XLS pois empresas precisam manipular os dados, e com pdf fica complicado.

Answer (score 1):

Abaixo um exemplo trabalhando com mPDF com codeigniter, no caso eu importo controlador PDF, e envio $data para a views **relatorio/pdf/body** e **relatorio/pdf/body**, no qual eu armazeno o PHP que irá gerar a view em HTML com as minhas informações. Depois basta somente escrever no arquivo.

Detalhe $result é um resultado de Query do Codeigniter

```
$this->load->library('pdf');
$pdf = $this->pdf->load();
$data['titulo_relatorio'] = 'Relatório';
$header = $this->load->view('relatorio/pdf/header', $data, true);
$pdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);
$pdf->SetFooter('Titulo Relatório' . '|Página {PAGENO}|' . date("d.m.Y") . '   ');

$dataResult['result'] = $result;
$pdf->WriteHTML($this->load->view('relatorio/pdf/body', $dataResult, true));
$pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, 'I');
```

E abaixo um exmplo do código da view

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>COLUNA 1</th>
            <th>COLUNA 2/th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
            foreach ($result as $row) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['campo1']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['campo2']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Resumindo, basicamente você irá gerar o HTML e escreve-lo em um arquivo PDF

Comment: Sveen,
Obrigado pela resposta.

Minha dúvida seria como gerar o modelo deste relatorio, ou seja, quero mostrar todos os resultados, mas eles devem estar separados por grupo, no qual cada grupo terá um subtotal....conforme o exemplo da imagem.